# Deploying Thinking Sphinx through Capistrano yields 'Column number 6 has no name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, capistrano, thinking-sphinx

I'm not exactly sure where the problem I'm running into is occurring. When I run the deploy task the rake thinking_sphinx:configure works fine, but then when it tries to index it this error occurs:

ERROR: index 'board_core': column 6 has no name. 
ERROR: index 'board_delta': column 6 has no name.

...and so on for all of my indexes and delta indexes. At first I thought this was a problem with capistrano, since I have the project setup on a windows machine and a mac, and the cap staging deploy deploys to an ubuntu setup.

The SQL for the query that seems to be erroring is:

```
SELECT `boards`.`id` * 5 + 2 AS `id` , CAST(`boards`.`name` AS CHAR) AS `name`, CAST(`boards`.`display_name` AS CHAR) AS `display_name`, CAST(`boards`.`description` AS CHAR) AS `description`, `boards`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 2576811075 AS `class_crc`, '2576811075' AS `subclass_crcs`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`boards`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `users`.`id` SEPARATOR ',') AS `user`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user_boards_boards`.`id` SEPARATOR ',') AS `user_board`, COUNT(user_boards.id) AS `num_users` FROM `boards`    LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_boards` ON (`boards`.`id` = `user_boards`.`board_id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `user_boards`.`user_id`)   LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_boards` user_boards_boards ON user_boards_boards.board_id = boards.id  WHERE `boards`.`id` >= $start AND `boards`.`id` <= $end AND `boards`.`delta` = 0 GROUP BY `boards`.`id`  ORDER BY NULL
```

..meaning that the part that's breaking is the select 0 as ``sphinx_deleted`\`, which seems fine to me (it works when calling it straight through mysql, minus the part of the where clause that uses $start and $end of course) so I don't know what could be causing the error. My only thought is that indexer from sphinx is erroring, but if that's the case then I still have no idea how to go about solving this.

Thanks in advance for any help/tips.

Answer (score 0):

What is the mysql server version, and mysql client version. This error occurs often when the client is running 5.1 or if there is a version mismatch.